# Cannot change service account user gcloud gcp

Tags: gcloud, service-accounts

I still wondering how supposed to do to change the service account user. Let say I have 2 service account (A and B), which each user has different role in different project. After done being use user B, when I want to change to service account A and access the resource, gcloud command says

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "user-B@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default": requires one of ["container.pods.list"] permission(s).
```

I'm done change my service account user with `gcloud config set account [service-account]`, but the gcloud still read another service account. Did I missed something?

Comment: Your question states that`gcloud` throws the error but the error itself suggests you're using `kubectl`. Can you confirm which it is? Google Cloud Platform has a concept of Service Accounts (e.g. `{foo}@{project}.iam.gserviceaccount.com`) and Kubernetes has an entirely distinct concept of Service Accounts.

Comment: Use this format: **gcloud auth activate-service-account test@development-123456.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=service_account.json** https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

Comment: Were the comments provided helpful to solve this issue? Also check this reference on [how to change the service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances?hl=en#changeserviceaccountandscopes).

Comment: @DazWilkin we used service account to access k8s resource. recently I added another service account to access another resource (lets say service account B). While using B, I cannot access my k8s resource. When I tried to access my k8s again and activate service account A, the output said I'm still used service account B and cannot reach the k8s resource. Even after I revoke the SA account of B, the error output still the same.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, I already done that but nothing change. the gcloud still read the user as service account B, even after I activate again service account for my k8s

Comment: @Alex sadly, not yet found the culprit. Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately still not get it done. I wonder if the gcloud auth can be refresh or clear token cache that may causing this issue.

Comment: After a while, suddenly my k8s resource can be reach again. I believe not doing anything except try to activate back the service account (I tried this before and not work even after restart the laptop). After I leave this on the weekend, now it works well again. I'm still thinking maybe I can do some clear cache but still don't know how to do that

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing and what you want. Please update your question to include the specific commands you're using to generate the error you describe. That it's working again without any obvious change suggests that the problem isn't resolved, just avoided. I assume a token expired and this is why the behavior changed.

Comment: I'm unclear whether you're using GKE's workload identity or you're trying to authenticate using different GCP Service Accounts. You can `gcloud auth activate-service-account` and `gcloud config set account {account}` to activate then swap between GCP (!) Service Accounts. I suspect (!) the `kubectl` auth plugins, hold tokens until expiry (an hour). I suspect that `A` or `B` has insufficient IAM permissions ([Kubernetes Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles)) but it's not possible to answer without more info.

Comment: @DazWilkin Oh, I missed something. You're right! `kubectl` auth plugin hold tokens until expiry. After 'activate' or 'config set' service account we can access the resource, but for `kubectl` I have to run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` to update my `kubectl` configuration to use `gke-gcloud-auth` plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a contrived example of what I think you're doing:

```bash
# gcloud is using my regular User credentials
gcloud config get account
me@gmail.com

# Access GKE as me@gmail.com
kubectl get pods --namespace=default
pod/foo-c7b7995df-vxrmh

# Authenticate as a GCP Service Account with **no** permissions
EMAIL="{ACCOUNT}@{PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
gcloud auth activate-service-account ${EMAIL} \
--key-file=${KEY_FILE}

# gcloud is now using the Service Account credentials
gcloud config get account
${EMAIL}

# Using new GKE auth plugin
gke-gcloud-auth-plugin \
| jq -r .status.expirationTimestamp
2022-00-00T17:10:00Z

# Need to either delete the token
# Or wait until 17:10 for it to expire
# Then...
kubectl get pods --namespace=default
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: ...
```

> **ERROR** `Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "{ACCOUNT}@{PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default": requires one of ["container.pods.list"] permission(s).`

One solution is to grant the GCP (!) Service Account one of the [Kubernetes Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#kubernetes-engine-roles) that has permission to list Pods, i.e. `container.pods.*` which is part of `roles/container.developer`:

```bash
# Grant the Service Account Kubernetes Engine role
ROLE="roles/container.developer"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=${ROLE}

# Try again
kubectl get pods --namespace=default --output=name
pod/foo-c7b7995df-vxrmh
```